How to set metadata for Token Program Standard (Not using Token Program Extension 2022)?
I am using solana-keygen grind and spl-token create-token
I want to use cli command to do these things.
When I use command spl-token create-token.
I created a token but it has no metadata, I want to update metadata but when created it is marked as not updatable. I don't know what to do here to be able to set metadata for my token?

The OG SPL token program doesn't natively support adding metadata to created tokens.
You can add Metadata using the Metaplex programs but they do not ship a CLI for doing this.
Token Metdata docs -> https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata
